# how to refresh images in HTML Preview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am showing an HTML preview containing an image in vscode.
If the html content is supposed to change, I call the update method of my TextDocumentContentProvider. The result is that in the HTML preview I see the updated text, but the image is still the old one, even though I changed the image file in the meantime. When closing the preview and reopening it the new image is displayed.
How can I force the HTML preview to reload the images?

update code:

```
provider = new HeapProvider(); //HeapProvider extends TextDocumentContentProvider
previewUri:string;
method updatePreview(){
  this.provider.update(this.previewUri)
  vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.previewHtml', this.previewUri,
    vscode.ViewColumn.Two).then((success) => { }, (reason) => {
      vscode.window.showErrorMessage(reason);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you pleas add your code

Comment: I added the code, but I guess it is not dependent on the code, since I'm just wondering how to force a reload of the images

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `workbench.action.webview.reloadWebviewAction` command that will refresh any visible webview.

This is only guaranteed to work for VS Code's real [Webview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview), not with the old `previewHtml` command. You can also set a webview's content again to force a refresh: `webview.webview.html = webview.webview.html`